# Are the set of all one-one functions f: A→A under the composition of mappings, forms a group or not

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics

A={ 1, 2, 3, 4 }
For group we check associativity, identity and inverse.
Clearly set A with composition as operation is associative but i can't figure out the other two things to check whether set of all one-one functions will be a group or not.

Comment: Injective functions on a finite set are bijections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint (Pigeonhole principle):

An injective function $A\to A$ is surjective if $A$ is finite.